# Check stat.count value in arraylist in <s:iterator> tag for struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

```
<% System.out.println("These indexed shall be shown on gui "+(ArrayList)request.getSession().getAttribute("selectedIndexes")); %>   // ArrayList value can be 2,3,5,9

  <s:iterator var="itr" value="#session.completeArrayList" status="stat">
 <s:if > //if stat.count value present in arraylist(selectedIndexes), then go to if loop
 </s:if

</s:iterator>
```

I dont know how to check `%{#stat.count}` value in `arraylist{selectedIndexes}` in `<s:if>` loop.
How shall i do this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is no need to even iterate over array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Struts2 uses [OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/) and it has `in` operator. So you can check it easily like that:

```
<s:iterator var="itr" value="#session.completeArrayList" status="stat">
  <s:if test="#stat.count in #session.selectedIndexes">
  </s:if
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried index and count property yet. Here is the [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) that shows example.

```
  <s:iterator status="status" value='%{0, 1}'>
      Index: <s:property value="%{#status.index}" /> <br />
      Count: <s:property value="%{#status.count}" /> <br />  
   </s:iterator>
```

will print

Index: 0
      Count: 1
      Index: 1
      Count: 2

Comment: I have already checked this, but i dont know how to check this count in Arraylist(stored in session), basically i am looking for contains method of arraylist in <s:if> loop

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:iterator var="itr" value="#session.completeArrayList" status="stat">
  <s:iterator var="ind" value="#session.selectedIndexes">
    <s:if test="#stat.count == #ind">
      I found #stat.count in selectedIndexes ArrayList
    </s:if>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: this is ok...If size of completeArrayList is m and size of selectedIndexes is n, then total iteration for <s:iterator> is m*n.....does struts 2 provide sth like if(selectedIndexes.contains #stat.count)?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a List of all the elements, and a sublist with selected elements, you could use a Map:

```
<s:iterator var="currentElement" value="#session.selectedIndexes" >
   <s:property value="#session.completeHashMap[#currentElement]" />
</s:iterator>
```

With a List, I've not clear what you want to achieve. If you want to enter the `<s:if/>` for every element in the sublist (and the sublist it's storing values and not indexes), like

> completeArrayList : {"a","b","c","d","e","f"}
>
> selectedIndexes : {"c","d"}

then you can use `contains` like this:

```
<s:iterator var="currentElement" value="#session.selectedIndexes" >
   <s:if test="%{#session.completeArrayList.contains(#currentElement)}">
      Selected Index with value 
      <s:property value="#currentElement" /> 
      found on bigList
   </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

If instead selectedIndexes is storing the INDEXES (and not the values) of the elements in the ArrayList,

> completeArrayList : {"a","b","c","d","e","f"}
>
> selectedIndexes : {2,3}

you can `get` them like this:

```
<s:iterator var="currentElement" value="#session.selectedIndexes" >
   <s:property value="#session.completeArrayList[#currentElement]" />
</s:iterator>
```